# svn SQLite compiled for 3.7.17, but running with 3.6.1

Tags: svn, sqlite

Trying to update a svn working copy using

```
svn update .
```

I get the following error:

```
svn: E200029: Couldn't perform atomic initialization
svn: E200030: SQLite compiled for 3.7.17, but running with 3.6.1
```

I am working with kubuntu 13.10 (with latest updates). I think that this suggests an error in in the packages (version mismatch). However I have this problem since a while and find only older similar reports on different OS's. So I wonder if something is wrong on my system. It would be useful to know what `3.6.1` is supposed to be the version of. It is of course not svn which is version `1.7.9` and `sqlite -version` yields `2.8.17`.

**EDIT**

It turned out that the apparent version mismatch is due to the to the simultaneous presence of a second version of sqlite (version 3.6.1 installed by Mathematica). Since this installation path is in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` svn seems to prefer this version and hence the mismatch. I could define an alias for svn or Mathematica which exports LD_LIBRARY_PATH before running the respective application, but I would prefer a more elegant solution. So, what is the recommended way to maintain two sqlite installations at the same time?

Comment: Did you try `svn upgrade` ?

Comment: Yes. `svn: E155019: Can't upgrade '' as it is not a pre-1.7 working copy directory`

Comment: I should mention that I am also using the kubuntu backports ppa. So it's maybe a bit more specific. I would like to avoid ppa-purge however as long as I don't know that such is the cause.

Comment: Maybe also noteworthy. This kind of operation usually works with kdesvn on my system. However it has a bug which leads to locks if there are version conflicts. No my working copy is locked and I cannot do a cleanup, because it produces a similar error as the update command.

Comment: Did you build and install svn or sqlite from source?

Answer (score 2):

The saucy version of [libsqlite3-0](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/libsqlite3-0) is 3.7.17-1ubuntu1. It should not be 3.6.1

Try to run:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install libsqlite3-0
```

And check the version with:

```
dpkg-query -s libsqlite3-0
```

Comment: Not the precise problem, but it helped me to find the solution quickly. I had installed Mathematica which apparently brings it's own version of libsqlite. Since I had to add the Mathematica libdir to $LD_LIBRARY_PATH svn seemingly tried to use this version. How would I force it to use the default sqlite version assuming that I want to continue using the old version with Mathematica?

Comment: Cool, could you please create a different question related to the co-existence of two sqlite providers on the same system and mark this question as solved?

Comment: I wanted to give you the chance to edit your answer ... I am grateful for your answer, but accepting it would not be entirely correct, I think. I can edit the question a bit if you want.

Comment: Feel free to propose an edit of my answer instead with what you did exactly.